# The constructor String(java.lang.String) is undefined

Tags: java, string

Im going over a study guide for a test that I have soon and decided to go into DrJava and try to figure something with `String` out. It worked fine once but now I keep getting the error `"The constructor String(java.lang.String) is undefined` and cant continue writing my code. I've looked up the different ways to write a string and none are working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
public class StudyGuide {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str = new String("Write a method that replicates toCharArray");
      System.out.println("The string says:");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not `String str = "Write a method that replicates toCharArray";`

Comment: Have you got your own class named `String`? Because there is such a constructor in `java.lang.String`, but you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I ran this code and it compiled and ran fine for me

Comment: That is what happens when I try to compile it. And I've tried it like "Write a method..." but I get the error message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to String"

Comment: `String` class of `util` pkg does have constructor of string, may b you are using `String` class of any other api or something else. I am sure this is not `java.lang.String`

Comment: No I don't have my own class named String. I am using DrJava if that helps with anything.

Comment: Your `type mismatch` error suggests another `String` type is in play. What `import` statements do you have? Is there another class called `String` in the same package?

Comment: @OAD String is in the 'util' package?

Comment: @Tom sorry `lang` :P typo

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the constructor for making String objects. Instead, use this:

```
String str= "Write a method that replicates toCharArray";
```

Then your program would look something like this:

```
public class StudyGuide {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = new String("Write a method that replicates toCharArray");
   System.out.println("The string says: "+str);
   }
}
```